# Why won't fur particles attach to model? (2.8)

Tags: rendering, particles

I, for the life of me, can't get the fur particles to attach to the model! Here's a screen-cap for those who want to see what I have to deal with (Render engine is Eevee, btw. Doesn't work in Cycles, either). I'd perfer to only share the model's file if absolutely necessary. [image: This is my school project. I need to get this thing animated by Thursday, but I can't make the fur particles follow the model as seen in the picture. Only the black lines that you use to lay down particles in the Particle Edit menu.]

Comment: Do you mean Hair or actual Particles

Comment: Hair. I used the Particle Edit menu to add it. Before that I used Quick Fur, then went from there.

Comment: Assuming Zesk is the hair do Ctrl + J to join or you could make a hair system on the model.

Comment: It kinda worked. Now the black lines do follow the model (there's some jankiness here and there). I did something, at least. I swear, every time I "fix" something I just break something else. I forgot what exactly I did, but now the fur won't show up in rendering! I think I'll try looking at other questions similar and my own model to see what the problem is exactly.

Comment: Sorry if I came off as aggressive earlier. Blender was (and still is) getting me all riled up and I needed to blow off steam. So, here's my current situation: the black lines that indicate where the fur goes follow the model and everything, but the fur isn't rendering now.  Everything else is fine.

Comment: Assuming the fur and Zesk are still separate try rendeing them individually.